# Repeating occupied pattern in Hilbert's hotel

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Imagine a countable infinite amount of empty rooms. When an infinite amount of guests come, they occupy the 1st, 3rd, 5th...(all odd) empty rooms. Therefore there's always an infinite amount of empty rooms, and occupied guests needn't move when new guests come.

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1 - 1
1 2 1 - 1 2 1 - 1 2 1 - 1 2 1 - 1
```

Same group of guests would leave together, so if group 1 leave, it results in

```
- 2 - - - 2 - - - 2 - - - 2 - - -
```

Notice that some rooms turn empty, so if another group of infinite guests come, it results in

```
3 2 - 3 - 2 3 - 3 2 - 3 - 2 3 - 3
```

Now room 1,2,4,6,7,... are occupied while 3,5,8,... are empty.

## Input

Given a list of moves(aka. some group join or some group leave). All join requests are labeled 1,2,3,... in order.

You can also choose to not read the joining label or not read join/leave value.

## Output

The shortest repeating pattern of occupied/empty.

## Test cases

```
[]            => [0]
[+1]          => [1,0]
[+1,+2]       => [1,1,1,0]
[+1,+2,-1]    => [0,1,0,0]
[+1,+2,-1,+3] => [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0]
[+1,-1]       => [0]
```

Shortest code wins

Comment: Can you output a cyclic permutation of the pattern, or does it have to start from the first room?

Comment: @CommandMaster Start from first. `10` and `01` are different(`01` should be impossible)

Comment: I guess we cannot output occupied rooms with their group number? (e.g. `[+1,+2,-1,+3] -> [3,2,0,3,0,2,3,0]`)

Comment: The correct output will always have length a power of 2, end in a 0, and contain an odd number of 0s.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 100 bytes

Returns a comma-separated binary string.

```javascript
a=>/(.*?)(,\1)*$/.exec(a.reduce((b,x)=>[...b,...b].map(q=v=>x<0|v?v+x&&v:q^=x),[0]).map(x=>+!!x))[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc9LDoIwEAbgvaeAxJAOLYXqzlg4CNak1GI0yFObLrw7CtFoiNjJzOqbf9KzNLJT7am@BmV10H3Oe8njEFE/AUR2DPxlSLXVCkna6sNNaYQyYoHHKaU0I8MQ9CJr1HDDY7uN7iYx2Hqe2TR7boGkkYARWB5j17UAKRO9qsquKjQtqiPKUSqczwNwwtB5ri0mCDMxRYz8YgSvxIQNNUNJMOa@zw7wDyV4Lb5So1fPpAdMTD7VPwA)

[99 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc9LDoIwEAbgvadgYUiHlpbqzlg4CNakQDEa5KlNF94dgWg0RJxJu@k3fzMXZVSXtuf65pdVpvtc9EqEDFEvAkQOHLw1o9rqFCna6uyeaoQSYkGEMaU0IeMl6VXVqBFGhHYfPExksHVds2uOwgKJAwkTsMMzswAxl31alV1VaFpUJ5SjWDqfAnAYc4ap1QxhLueIk1@M4I2csbEXKPGn3Pe3I/xDCd7Kr9TgdRbSfS5nS/VP) if we use `NaN` for unoccupied

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                 // a[] = input array
/(.*?)(,\1)*$/       // a regular expression that looks for the shortest
                     // prefix which, when repeated a whole number of
                     // times with a leading comma, allows to reach the
                     // end of the string
.exec(               // apply this to:
  a.reduce((b, x) => //   for each element x in a[],
                     //   using the array b[] as the accumulator:
    [...b, ...b]     //     append b[] to itself
    .map(q =         //     initialize q to a NaN'ish value
      v =>           //     for each element v in the resulting array:
      x < 0 | v ?    //       if x is negative or v is not 0:
        v + x && v   //         append 0 if v = -x, or v otherwise
      :              //       else:
        q ^= x       //         toggle q between 0 and x and append that
    ),               //     end of map()
    [0]              //     initialize the accumulator to [0]
  )                  //   end of reduce()
  .map(x => +!!x)    //   update each value to either 0 or 1
                     //   implicit coercion to a string
)[1]                 // end of exec(); return the prefix
```

Comment: Upvote for _NaN'ish_

Comment: @corvus_192 T/F(`.map(x=>x>0)`) feels better to me

Comment: @l4m2 corvus_192 was referring to the comment _initialize q to a NaN'ish value_. (I added the 99-byte version later.)

Comment: @Arnauld T/F is also 99 bytes

Comment: @l4m2 I find it less readable. We could also do inverted T/F for [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc9LDoIwEAbgvafAxJAOlEJ1ZywcpNakQDEa5KlNF94dhWg0jdjJzOqbf9Kz1LLPulNzDao6V0PBBsniEBEvAYT3FLxVSJRRGZKkU/ktUwil2ACLOSEkxeMQ5CIb1DLNYrOL7jrRvnFdvW0PzADmkYAJGBYvDQCnYsjqqq9LRcr6iArEhfN5AE4YOs@lhYV8KmxE8S@G/bWw2FgzFAdT7vvsCP9Q7G/EV2r06pn0gArrU8MD).

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>28</s>  24 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
N;`⁹¬Tm2Ʋ¦A¬ẹ¦ʋƒ0ṠŒṖEƇḢḢ
```

A full program* that accepts the register list and prints a Jelly representation of the pattern list.

<sup>* Only a full program to handle specifically `[] => [0]` for which the monadic Link would yield the integer `0`</sup>

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/POuFR485Da0JyjY5tOrTM8dCah7t2Hlp2qvvYJIOHOxccnfRw5zTXY@0PdywCov///0drG@poG@noAknjWAA)**

Replacing `ŒṖ` with `sJ$` will be faster if you want to [try slightly longer inputs](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/POuFR485Da0JyjY5tOrTM8dCah7t2Hlp2qvvYJIOHOxcUe6m4Hmt/uGMREP3//z/aUMdIR9dQx1hH10jHRMdUx0xHF8g21dE1iwUA).

#### How?

The idea is to process the *moves* in turn maintaining a prefix that starts at `[0]` and doubles in length at each *move* either occupying every other empty room with a copy of *move* or removing all occurrences of the negative of *move*. Once this is done we can then find the shortest prefix that repeats to give the same.

Actually, the implementation is a little more convoluted - rather than the "either or" above, we process negated values of the *moves*, always add these to every other unoccupied room, take absolute values and then always remove all occurrences of the negated *move* from all rooms. This saves some precious bytes.

```
N;`⁹¬Tm2Ʋ¦A¬ẹ¦ʋƒ0ṠŒṖEƇḢḢ - Main Link: list of moves, Moves
N                        - negate {Moves} (vectorises)
               ƒ0        - start with 0 and reduce {that} by:
              ʋ          -   last four links as a dyad - f(Rooms, -Move)
 ;`                      -     {Rooms} concatenate {Rooms} -> R2
         ¦               -     sparse application...
        Ʋ                -     ...to indices: last four links as a monad - f(R2):
    ¬                    -       logical NOT {R2}
     T                   -       truthy indices of {that} -> I
       2                 -       two
      m                  -       {I} modulo-slice {2
                                   -> indices of every other empty room
   ⁹                     -     ...apply: set to chain's right argument = -Move
          A              -     absolute value {that} (vectorises)
             ¦           -     sparse application...
            ẹ            -     ...to indices: indices of {-Move}
           ¬             -     ...apply: logical NOT
                 Ṡ       - signs {that} -> occupied or not indicators
                  ŒṖ     - partitions of {that}
                     Ƈ   - keep those {patitions} for which:
                    E    -   all equal? -> repetitive partitions
                      Ḣ  - head {that} -> shortest repetitive partition
                       Ḣ - head {that} -> shortest possible prefix
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>223</strike> 202 bytes

Oh boy. Cool challenge, cant wait to see what everyone can do!

slowly chipping away I guess...

```python
def f(g,h=[0]):
 for q in g:
  if[q]<h:h=[w*(w-q)for w in h];continue
  h=h+h;p=1
  for i,w in enumerate(h):
   if w<1:h[i]=p*q;p=1-p
 while h==h[:len(h)//2]*2:h=h[:len(h)//2]
 return[1-(i<1)for i in h]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7NDsIgEITvfYo9QqVR6q2WJyEcjIK7iVJKaIhPX0Fj4s9tZ@bb2Q33hJPfr@vZOnDsIlDpneFDA26KMAN5uBQB5PRsRhxKnFuWu5nXPNcczeE0@UR@sQVEhRs8BCXLXBEST8j65WbjMVmGtbwWQh7lgJqMCu1cN7rQQEa62lKiUA9X6wu93fam7cvhL6eBaNMSvZYdo1E@v6HXN2uI5BNzjHHOm7fQ0nwoJkXPf7SQ/47Y/3iVWR8)

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <strike>215</strike> 195 bytes

stealing Ajax1234's walrus operator while loop o7

```python
def f(g,h=[0]):
 for q in g:
  if[q]<h:h=[w*(w-q)for w in h];continue
  h=h+h;p=1
  for i,w in enumerate(h):
   if w<1:h[i]=p*q;p=1-p
 while h==(k:=h[:len(h)//2])*2:h=k
 return[1-(i<1)for i in h]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU7NjsIgEL73KeY4dGlc6sVgeRLCweyCQ1RKCQ3x6StoTDbubb7f@eI90xz2h5i27dc6cHjmpPS3YbIDNydYwAc4VwDe6cVMJKtceizDwppemk7m@DOH7MNqq5EUfdExKlHvZvH8abJhvdl0yhaplbdCKJOQpL1RsV9aYogdFPJXW0sUXqQiLa821MRuNxrWj/X7pYNk85qCFgP6STxn@NeMLSYfMjpExlj3BlqYPwgFH9kH5uI/w/cfXPNsDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 59 bytes

```
⊞υ⁰Ｆθ¿‹ι⁰ＵＭυ∧⁺ικκ«≔⁺υυυＦΦ⌕Ａυ⁰﹪λ²§≔υκι»≔⭆υ¬¬ιηＷ⁼η×²÷η²≔÷η²ηη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7NasMwEITP8VPscUUUaN2jT6Y/EGiKob2FHESkxEvWUmNJaaH02d1V3F56GK3YGX2jfW/GfTA8TV2OPWYNN6qpDmEEPCugA@CzixGp7BVszPt9GAbjbUm2MjrOV/ekilQDjqODr2rRxkhHP/uSzaqoqRZX9BNxcqMMb1vmuVXDJtjMAVlDraRsJrRp7a37LJmTBhLEd/XLfk0j@aP8qZgvIWERyVMNveQ@emIH@HjOhiP2Gt5ocBFrDWufHuhC1pVt6forw3/ODOqkJqHcpmm7Xd7qZa1Xct7tdtPqwj8) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⁰
```

Start with one empty room.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop over the input values.

```
¿‹ι⁰
```

If it is negative, then...

```
ＵＭυ∧⁺ικκ«
```

Discard those values whose sum is zero, otherwise:

```
≔⁺υυυ
```

Duplicate the list.

```
ＦΦ⌕Ａυ⁰﹪λ²
```

Loop over alternate indices of the empty rooms. (Filtering is golfier than slicing alternate indices.)

```
§≔υκι
```

Fill the room at this index.

```
»≔⭆υ¬¬ιη
```

Convert the rooms to a binary string of occupancy.

```
Ｗ⁼η×²÷η²
```

While the string equals half of itself repeated twice, ...

```
≔÷η²η
```

... halve the length of the string.

```
η
```

Output the final string.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 227 bytes

```py
def f(m):
 h=[0]*(2**sum(i>0for i in m))
 for i in m:
  if i<0:h=[[0,l][l!=-i]for l in h]
  else:
   k=1
   for j,a in enumerate(h):h[j]=[a,i][k%2 and 0==a];k+=a==0
 while h==(k:=h[:len(h)//2])*2:h=k
 return[int(i>0)for i in h]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BbsMgEETv/ortoRLYRMHkEtFufwTtASkgiDGxiK2qX@9CD6mU9rSamTfS7PK1hls@nZey7xfnwbOZ6w4CGkk9U31/32YWP6S/FYgQM8ycd/CrKgvRQ3yXunaMFIlMesFDpMakxgSqjEt311iYcGynpVdhW@7yNrtiV8cC18FcCY0Vkcz0qsDmC0hES2/TgBZRdvAZYnJ1ILJJYzA6uVyLx6Mi3qs6YuqguHUr2cS8tun8sTbQvpTmemao/vEQw/gkxaD@OuIw/muK4fTs/5D7Nw)

Comment: 225 bytes: https://tio.run/##bY/BasMwEETv/ortoSDZMpGcS3Cy/RGhg2hktJEtG1Um5OtduYcU0l4WZuYNzC6P7Od4PC1p265ugIFNvK/Ao5amZl1df60Tow85zAkIKMLEeQW/qrBAA9BF9qWjpRiNHt@wJbMz4854c/6cY6a4ugIHVOXu4U3YPXZxnVyy2THPe69vBrUVZHR478DGK0hEa86hQYsoK7h7Gl3Zhyz06HU/uliKh0NneN2VDaGC5PKaolYto4viz63ebEuimNnAtClfPEWjXqRour@OaNW/pmiOr/4PuX0D